# R: Select data across multiple columns and conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe called `test` that looks like this:

```
> test
    dx1     dx2    dx3
1   659     658    657
2   653     651    690 
3   249     786    654
4   647     655    656
5   900     654    658
6   800     224    104
```

I want to keep only the observations that have at least one column that falls in the range 650 - 660, inclusive. In this case, the result should look like:

```
    dx1     dx2    dx3
1   659     658    657
2   653     651    690 
3   249     786    654
4   647     655    656
5   900     654    658
```

So far, I've tried using `test[test %in% c(650 : 660)]`, but this returns a list of numbers in `test` that satisfy the range without maintaining the dataframe structure. How can I apply the range condition to multiple columns in a dataframe?

Comment: Here is a method using `rowSums`: `test[rowSums(test > 649 & test < 661) > 0,]`.

Comment: Here's another (unnecessarily over-complicated) possible solution ```library(data.table) ; setDT(test)[, .SD[Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, between, 650, 660))]]```

Comment: another way in base `R` : `test[apply(test,1,function(x) any(x>=650 &x<=660)),]`

Comment: @lmo You could post that if you're not busy dupe-hunting. An alternative would be `as.logical` instead of `> 0`.

Comment: All of these work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Frank. There exist similar questions if not outright dupes, but I can't find a good example at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succinctly:

```
test <- test[apply(test, 1, function(x) any(x >= 650 & x <= 660)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

```
# set up your dataset
dx1 <- c(659, 653, 249, 647, 900, 800)
dx2 <- c(658, 651, 786, 655, 654, 224)
dx3 <- c(657, 690, 654, 656, 658, 104)
# bind the created vectors together
test <- cbind(dx1, dx2, dx3)

# filter based on your conditions    
test[(test[, 1] >= 650 & test[, 1] <= 660) | 
     (test[, 2] >= 650 & test[, 2] <= 660)| 
     (test[, 3] >= 650 & test[, 3] <= 660), ]
```

Comment: It doesn't matter here, but OP claims to have a data.frame, while your construction is a matrix.

Comment: This would result in what I'm looking for, but I have many more than three columns to type out. Any chance your solution could be generalized?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and `any` to find the rows of interest and then subset your original.

```
goodvals <- apply(test <= 660 & test >= 650, 1, any)
test[goodvals, ]
```